# Why my code is causing unnecessary recompositions in jetpack compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have written some code that shows the images and videos. I'm using viewModel but in the code below `MediaScreenBody()` composable is recomposing unneccesarly even there is no change in the data. Also it causing its child composables to recompose as same time or even more than the count of `MediaSceenBpody()` . I tried many ways like using by with collectAsState but those were causing even 10x recompositons. At the first time when app is launched there is only one composition of every single composable. And then if i interact with app e.g. swiping or scrolling then it recomposes the `MediaSceenBpody()` and its child content as well. It also causing lagging behavior to the scrolling and swiping due to recompositions. I did somereseach and i found that the pagerState may be causing this issue. I tried setting the pagerState to diffenrt number and recompositions are also changed to that number. But please keep inmind that somtimes it causes more than that. Its not neccessary there that it will recompose only to the number of pageState. I have shared this just for your reference.

```
@Composable
fun MediaScreen(onMediaItemClick: () -> Unit) {
    val mediaViewModel: MediaViewModel = viewModel(
        factory = MediaViewModel.Factory
    )
    val photoUIState = mediaViewModel.photoUIState.collectAsState()
    val videoUIState = mediaViewModel.videoUIState.collectAsState()

    ScreenContent(
        mediaViewModel = mediaViewModel,
        photoUIState = photoUIState,
        videoUIState = videoUIState,
        onMediaItemClick = onMediaItemClick
    )


}


@Composable
fun ScreenContent(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    mediaViewModel: MediaViewModel,
    photoUIState: State<PhotoUIState>,
    videoUIState: State<VideoUIState>,
    onMediaItemClick: () -> Unit
) {
    val topBarScrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.enterAlwaysScrollBehavior()
    Scaffold(
        modifier = modifier
            .nestedScroll(topBarScrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection),
        topBar = {
            TopAppBarContent(topBarScrollBehavior)
        }
    ) { contentPadding ->
        MediaScreenBody(
            contentPadding = contentPadding,
            mediaViewModel = mediaViewModel,
            photoUIState = photoUIState,
            videoUIState = videoUIState,
            onMediaItemClick = onMediaItemClick
        )

    }
}


@Composable
fun TopAppBarContent(scrollBehavior: TopAppBarScrollBehavior? = null) {
    TopAppBar(
        title = {
            Text(
                text = stringResource(id = R.string.app_name)
            )
        },
        colors = TopAppBarDefaults.topAppBarColors(
            containerColor = if (isSystemInDarkTheme()) cs_theme_dark_topBar else cs_theme_light_topBar,
            titleContentColor = Color.White
        ),
        scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior
    )
}

@Composable
fun MediaScreenBody(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    mediaViewModel: MediaViewModel,
    contentPadding: PaddingValues,
    photoUIState: State<PhotoUIState>,
    videoUIState: State<VideoUIState>,
    onMediaItemClick: () -> Unit,
) {

    val pagerState = rememberPagerState {
        3
    }

    var selectedTabIndex by rememberSaveable {
        mutableIntStateOf(0)
    }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(contentPadding)
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        TabRow(
            selectedTabIndex = selectedTabIndex,
            containerColor = if (isSystemInDarkTheme()) cs_theme_dark_topBar else cs_theme_light_topBar,
            contentColor = Color.White
        ) {
            tabs.forEachIndexed { index, tabData ->
                Tab(
                    selected = index == selectedTabIndex,
                    onClick = { selectedTabIndex = index },
                    text = { Text(text = tabData.title) }
                )
            }
        }

        HorizontalPager(
            modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            state = pagerState
        ) { currentPage ->
            when (currentPage) {
                0 -> {
                    when (photoUIState.value.mediaPhotos) {
                        is PhotoLoadingState.Loading -> LoadingScreen()
                        is PhotoLoadingState.Success -> SuccessScreen(
                            mediaList = (photoUIState.value.mediaPhotos as PhotoLoadingState.Success).photos,
                            onDownloadClick = {
                                val isSaved = mediaViewModel.saveMedia(it)
                            },
                            onMediaItemClick = onMediaItemClick
                        )

                        is PhotoLoadingState.Error -> ErrorScreen(onRetry = { mediaViewModel.loadPhotos() })
                    }
                }

                1 -> {
                    when (videoUIState.value.mediaVideos) {
                        is VideoLoadingState.Loading -> LoadingScreen()
                        is VideoLoadingState.Success -> SuccessScreen(
                            mediaList = (videoUIState.value.mediaVideos as VideoLoadingState.Success).videos,
                            onDownloadClick = {},
                            onMediaItemClick = onMediaItemClick
                        )

                        is VideoLoadingState.Error -> ErrorScreen(onRetry = { mediaViewModel.loadVideos() })
                    }
                }

                else -> {
                    val context = LocalContext.current
                    Button(onClick = {
                        Toast.makeText(
                            context,
                            "I'm working m third pager",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                        ).show()
                    }) {
                        Text(text = "Hello")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit -**
As there were many suggestions about not passing the state or viemodel as parameter. I tried calling it direclty within the `MediaScreenBody()` where HorizontalPager is used. But it is causing more than 40-50 recompositon when content is scrolled its got more worse. This is how i tried moving the code to `MediaScreenBody()` -

```
val mediaViewModel: MediaViewModel = viewModel(
        factory = MediaViewModel.Factory
    )
    val photoUIState = mediaViewModel.photoUIState.collectAsState()
    val videoUIState = mediaViewModel.videoUIState.collectAsState()
```

Comment: First of all you are not supposed to pass the ```State<>``` in composable parameter rather pass the data only. and if you pass state then you don't need to pass ```ViewModel``` instance to the composable

Comment: I believe you can use this library https://github.com/theapache64/rebugger to know what causing your compsable to get re-composition

Comment: @ChiragThummar Thanks for your attention. I tried passing the data direclt like this `val videoUIState by mediaViewModel.videoUIState.collectAsState()` then passing videoUIState to `ScreenContent()`

Answer (score 0):

The problem for the unnecessary recompositions is because of ViewModel. A viewmodel is always considered unstable in a composable method. To avoid such recompositions, you can consider the below two ways:

1. Never pass the viewmodel to your child composables. Have a callback to intimate the event and use your viewmodel in that callback.

In your case, you can avoid passing viewmodel to the MediaScreenBody() method and use viewmodel in ScreenContent() method itself.Something like this:

```
fun MediaScreenBody(
modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
contentPadding: PaddingValues,
onMediaItemClick: () -> Unit,
onPhotoError: () -> Unit,
onVideoError: () -> Unit
)
```

You can use the last two callbacks to load from viewmodel again.

2. Declare a lambda outside the method call where you tend to use viewmodel. Sometimes using the viewmodel in the callback directly can lead to unnecessary recompositions. A sample is given below:

   val onClickLambda = remember<() -> Unit> { { // viewmodel access } }

   @Composable fun Test() { Button(onClick = onClickLambda) {} }

Comment: I didnt get it. Would you mind to refactor my code and then provide it. Thankyou

Comment: You used the viewmodel to load photos and videos in MediaScreenBody. Try to use the last two callbacks i provided in the method to call the loadPhotos() and loadVideos() method. In short, don't pass the viewmodel directly to the MediaScreenBody() method.